# How to perform map, when mapping relies on previous map config?

Tags: automapper

The below mapping between Volunteer & IVolunteerViewDTO works perfectly fine. I can call a REST api and receive a list of IVolunteerViewDTO mapped using AutoMapper. However, I can't figure out how to get Registration working with IRegistrationDTO. AutoMapper throws an exception and says: `InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Proxy<RSMuseum.Services.DTOs.IVolunteerViewDTO_RSMuseum.Services_Version=1.0.0.0_Culture=neutral_PublicKeyToken=null>' to type 'RSMuseum.Services.DTOs.VolunteerViewDTO'.`

```
    public IMapper GetMapper()
    {
        var mc = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Volunteer, IVolunteerViewDTO>()
              .ForMember(dest => dest.GuildName,
             opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Guilds.Select(x => x.GuildName)))
             .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName,
             opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Person.FirstName))
              .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName,
             opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Person.LastName));

            cfg.CreateMap<Guild, IGuildDTO>();

            cfg.CreateMap<Repository.Entities.Registration, IRegistrationDTO>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Guild,
                    opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Guild))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Volunteer,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Volunteer));
        });

        mc.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        IMapper m = new Mapper(mc, t => _container.GetInstance(t));

        return m;
    }
```

The dest.Volunteer is the DTO and the src.Volunteer is the entity itself. When I comment out the need for the VolunteerDTO on my RegistrationDTO, everything is perfectly fine and no exceptions at all. Question is how to fix.

Comment: If I understood correctly, IRegistrationDTO contains VolunteerDTO  and Repository.Entities.Registration contains IVolunteerViewDTO. Is that correct? Could you elaborate more on your last sentense?

Comment: Registration entity contains Volunteer entity. IRegistrationDTO contains IVolunteerViewDTO. So in my last sentence, if I comment out the IVolunteerViewDTO property, within my IRegistrationDTO, I can map perfectly fine and call my REST-api to GetRegistrations. The problem arrises when I need to map dest.Volunteer (type: IVolunteerViewDTO) from src.Volunteer (type: Volunteer). It's like it doesn't know how to do it properly, because it doesn't reference to its own cfg.CreateMap<Volunteer, IVolunteerViewDTO> I defined. Hmm